# How to create and restore a backup from SqlAlchemy?

Tags: python, serialization, sqlalchemy, pylons

I'm writing a Pylons app, and am trying to create a simple backup system where every table is serialized and tarred up into a single file for an administrator to download, and use to restore the app should something bad happen.

I can serialize my table data just fine using the [SqlAlchemy serializer](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/serializer.html), and I can deserialize it fine as well, but I can't figure out how to commit those changes back to the database.

In order to serialize my data I am doing this:

```
from myproject.model.meta import Session
from sqlalchemy.ext.serializer import loads, dumps
q = Session.query(MyTable)
serialized_data = dumps(q.all())
```

In order to test things out, I go ahead and truncation `MyTable`, and then attempt to restore using `serialized_data`:

```
from myproject.model import meta
restore_q = loads(serialized_data, meta.metadata, Session)
```

This doesn't seem to do anything... I've tried calling a `Session.commit` after the fact, individually walking through all the objects in `restore_q` and adding them, but nothing seems to work.

What am I missing? Or is there a better way to do what I'm aiming for? I don't want to shell out and directly touch the database, since SqlAlchemy supports different database engines.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to use [`Session.merge()`](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/reference/orm/sessions.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.merge) method instead of `Session.add()` to put deserialized object back into the session.

Comment: Where is the `Session.add()` call in the OP that needs replacing? Are there lines of code missing?

Comment: @Efren Missing lines are described in OP with "walking through all the objects in restore_q and adding them" phrase.

Comment: note the OP links to docs for Expression Serializer Extension in SLQAlchemy v1.3 - in v1.4 docs for the same page there is a warning about security consideration related to use of pickle... 
I am working with untrusted input data in db, so will be looking elsewhere for backup/restore methodology.  Furthermore, [in v2.0 docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/serializer.html) it is flagged as:

Legacy Feature

The serializer extension is legacy and should not be used for new development.