# sqlalchemy serializer merging

Tags: python, database, serialization, sqlalchemy

Im sending sqlalchemy objects trough net to another machine. First I serialize it to a string, then crypting and sending.
I serialize it with:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.ext.serializer import loads, dumps
engine = create_engine(connection_str)
S = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine, expire_on_commit=False))
session = S()

data = session(MyObj).all()
serialized = pickle.dumps([dumps(d) for d in data])

crypted = crypt(serialized) #encrypting the serialized data
send(machine, crypted)      #sending encripted data to 'machine'
```

and on the other machine:

```
encrypted = get_data()
serialized = decrypt(encrypted)
data = [loads(d, Base.metadata, S) for d in pickle.loads(serialized)]

for d in data:
    session.merge(d)
session.commit()
```

but it throws: `(IntegrityError) node_type.id may not be NULL u'INSERT INTO myobj (col1, col2) VALUES (?, ?)' (None, None)`

and when i try to print the `data` it throws: `DetachedInstanceError Instance <MyObj at 0x24e0c70> is not bound to a Session; attribute refresh operation cannot proceed`
or an:`ObjectDeletedError`

what is the problem?

here:
[How to create and restore a backup from SqlAlchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786664/how-to-create-and-restore-a-backup-from-sqlalchemy) is told that `session.merge()` would be fine, but it didnt work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs for [sqlalchemy.ext.serializer](http://sqlalchemy.readthedocs.org/en/rel_0_8/core/serializer.html?highlight=serializer#sqlalchemy.ext.serializer):

> "The serializer module is only appropriate for query structures. It is
>   not needed for [...] instances of user-defined classes"

Maybe try to just use pickle and not sqlalchemy.ext.serializer for this use case.

Comment: ok now it works! I use `pickle`(not the `sqlalchemy.ext.serializer`), but my objects(tables) must have `__getstate__` `__setstate__` methods and these methods must all the columns initialise

Comment: Actually I saw your previous comment where you said it hadn't worked and did some research. Maybe you don't need `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` if you expunge your objects from the session before calling `dumps()` on them. I haven't tested though.