# Storing/Copying PostgreSQL Database to Another Server through SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I know there are ways of storing data/tables from one server to another, such as the instruction provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237725/copying-postgresql-database-to-another-server). However, due to I use python to scrape, create, and store data, I am wondering that whether I could fulfill this process by directly using **SQLAlchemy**. More precisely, after I store the scraped data in the database I create through SQLAlchemy in my own computer, can I simultaneously store.copy those database/tables to another computer/server directly through **SQLAlchemy**? Can anyone help? Thanks so much.

Comment: check this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786664/how-to-create-and-restore-a-backup-from-sqlalchemy) i think it will be helpfull.

Comment: @suhail areekkan I'm new to both SQLAlchemy and PostgreSQL, could you explain how it could work with more details?